# How to Keep Desktop icons automatically arranged Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, wayland, desktop-icons

How I can Keep Desktop icons automatically arranged Ubuntu 17.10 wayland?

Comment: **Close Voters:** This question was asked way back in February 2018 when 17.10 was supported. So, this question isn't off-topic.